# Data analysis in Python not iterating through records

Tags: python

I want to group records in a table by their sum of a value, assign a unique number this group, etc. This is what the below script should do, but I am getting the following error when running it in shell:

```
line 5, in <module>
d = dict(reader(infile))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
from csv import reader
with open('file.csv',mode='r') as infile:
d = dict(reader(infile))

dictf = {}
for key, value in d.iteritems():
try:
    dictf[key] = float(value)
except: pass

flag = 1
sum = 0
final = {}
sumpop = []

for key in sorted(d.iterkeys()):
if 45000.0 < sum < 55000.0 or sum > 50000:
    flag += 1
    sumpop.append(sum)
    sum = 0
sum += dictf[key]
try:
    final [flag] += " " + key
except:
    final [flag] = key

output = open("output.csv","w+")
output.write("TRACT,POPULATION,NUMBER,FLAG,SUMPOP\n")

for key,sum in zip(sorted(final.iterkeys()),sumpop):
flag = "1"
for value in final[key].split(" "):
    output.write( value + "," + dictf[value].__str__() + "," + key.__str__() + ","      +  flag + "," + sum.__str__() + "\n")
    flag = ""

output.close()
```

The output.csv will have 100% of input records, but is assigned a Number (a group ID) - part of a set of records whose population values total ~50,000.

Comment: Can you paste here you sample .csv file?

Comment: Syed - yes. Here:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35610819/file.csv

Answer (score 1):

the csv reader function returns a generator of lists, in it's default, every such list represents a line and the list elements are the words in that line.

reading a csv file into a dictionary should be done a little different, depend of the csv file structure, something like:

```
from csv import reader
d = {}
with open('file.csv',mode='r') as infile:
    for idx, line in enumerate(reader(infile)):
        if idx:
            d[line[0]] = line[1]
```

EDIT: added skipping first line after seeing shared csv file

Comment: thanks. Adding this I get the following: line 9, in <module>
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @user4015 Probably you are using `python 3.x`, simply replace `iteritems()` with `items()`.

Comment: @Ray BINGO!  Now it works 100%. thank you. Curious what Python version iter is used with?

Comment: @user4015 Python 2.x should be, like the one on my machine.

Comment: @Ray is that the commonly used version as it is more stable?

Comment: @user4015 Both versions are fine in terms of stabability, only some syntax differences you might need to consider.